# JWT bearer token is placed in the query string after authentication

Tags: angular, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am successfully authenticating to Angular2 ADAL based app with Azure Active Directory OAuth2 service.
As soon as I authenticate, the Token is appended to the url in a querystring. 
Like so:

```
 http://localhost:4200/dashboard#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1...
```

I understand this seems like the default behavior, however, is there a way to prevent the token from displaying in the Url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [code sample](https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/ng2-adal-QuickStart), I am not able to reproduce the issue. It seems to be a code issue, you may refer the code sample about how to protect the Angular 2 with Azure AD.

After you try to run the code sample, you may find the compile issue. To make it work please use `@types/jasmine` with version `2.5.36` and `typescript` with version `2.3.4`

You can run the command below to update the packages after you install the packages:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript@2.3
npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine@2.5.36
```

If you still have the problem, you may share a runnable code sample to help reproducing this issue.

Comment: Hmm, isn't the token included in the URL because of implicit flow?

Comment: When the application integrate with Azure AD, it will log the request URL. And after redirect from Azure ad with the token, the adal library should retrieve the token and replace the URL using the the request URL which logged before send the login request.(refer [adal.js#L1027](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L1027))